# Google Sheets: Return Unique Name and Associated ID

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My Google Sheets workbook includes multiple sheets with tables containing a name in column A and an associated ID in column B.

My goal is to write a formula so it returns only one name and corresponding ID for each instance of name/ID found.

Some names do not have an associated ID in column B. If so, I need just one unique instance of the name in column A.

Other names may be duplicated, but have non-matching IDs in column B. If so, I need one instance of each name with its associated non-matching ID.

A helper column will not be accepted by others who work with this data.

The closest I've come to getting what I need is with this formula:

`=UNIQUE(QUERY({'Mar 2017'!A5:B;'Apr 2017'!A5:B;'May 2017'!A5:B;'Jun 2017'!A5:B}, "SELECT Col1, Col2 WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Col1 ASC"))`

If the name in column A is not already associated with an ID in column B, I need one unique instance of the name in column A without an associated ID. The formula shown above fails to do that.

Please refer to my [sample Google Sheets workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1if5hzjTTC8AFY5ed8y4aNLtiYNfXjrDo9pgsr_Wex0M/edit#gid=0) for a visual example.

Comment: I have tried changing the `OR` logic to `AND` logic from your existing formula, does this satisfy your desired output?

Comment: @George: Changing from the `OR` to the `AND` definitely gets closer to a solution, at least in the simplified example described here. As you may have noticed, however, it still doesn't capture names that are not paired with any ID (for example, Jacqueline, on row 58 of the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1if5hzjTTC8AFY5ed8y4aNLtiYNfXjrDo9pgsr_Wex0M/edit#gid=0) I linked to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ,reduce(,tocol(J:J,1),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,indirect(c&"!A5:B")))),
     name_,index(Σ,,1), id_,index(Σ,,2),
     reduce(tocol(,1),unique(sort(tocol(name_,1))),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,let(Λ,unique(filter(id_,name_=c,id_<>"")),hstack(wrapcols(c,counta(Λ),c),ifna(Λ)))))))
```

- *`Tab names` are listed in `Column_J`(as in screenshot) from where they are picked up by the formula*

[image]

Comment: For some reason, when I try your approach, I get the following errors:
**NAME**: _Error Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is '42795!A5:B'. It is not a valid cell/range reference._
**ID**: _Error Function INDEX parameter 3 value is 2. Valid values are between 0 and 1 inclusive._
I'm hoping those errors will also display for you on the example spreadsheet linked-to above.

Comment: Format the column (where tab names are listed) to **Plain Text** and try

Comment: Thank you. After I ran up the street and got myself a caffeinated beverage, then came back and looked at the spreadsheet again, I figured out the formatting issue immediately. Then I saw your message confirming that. Sometimes we just need a bit of help to concentrate our focus. :-) Do you have a suggestion for incorporating the sheet references from column J into the formula itself?

Comment: Just use in the style of `{"Mar 2017";"Apr 2017"}` in place of `tocol(J:J,1)`

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the time you took to craft this solution.